# Want to change UIbutton to an image of my choice

Tags: xcode

```
UIButton *openButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
openButton.frame = CGRectMake((main.frame.size.width/2)-15, (main.frame.size.height/2)+75, 30, 30);
openButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
openButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
openButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
openButton.layer.borderColor = themeColor.CGColor;
[openButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[openButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
```

This is my open button's code that was already implemented into the mod menu but I really want to change it to a sample image instead of a circle. I tried changing it to an UIImage but I am not sure how to do it properly since i am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
yourBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ImgName"), for: .normal)
```

Please convert to objective c. `setImage` is a property of UIButton for image setting.

It may helps you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A part from question:

> i really want to change it to a sample image instead of a circle

seems like a problem with:

```
openButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
```

Removing this line should give you actual image on button.